# Receive ,display and incorporate?

Tags: cda

Is someone tried already the receive, display and incorporate CCDA document?

Can someone give me a not technical explanation for this one?

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in short, yes - C-CDA documents are XML files that can be transmitted to other organizations or vendors. The XML needs to be parsed - meaning you need to know what you are looking for in terms of patient information - then normalized (JSON) with objects created (javascript) that can be called from the HTML or whatever you're building. It's very possible and there are several resources out there, such as BlueButton+, but I wouldn't suggest moving forward with any project until you have someone who has a clinical or health admin background.